# Data transfer from Hive to Google Storage/Big Query

Tags: apache-spark, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-dataflow

I have some Hive tables in an on-premise hadoop cluster.
I need to transfer the tables to BigQuery in google cloud.

Can you suggest any google tools or any open source tools for the data transfer?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

BigQuery can [import Avro files](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/loading-data#loading_avro_files).

This means you can do something like `INSERT overwrite table target_avro_hive_table SELECT * FROM source_hive_table;`

You can then load the underlying .avro files into BigQuery via the `bq` command line tool or using the console UI:

`bq load --source_format=AVRO your_dataset.something something.avro`

Comment: I'm looking for a framework or data pipeline to transfer the data from Hive table to BigQuery like Sqoop

Comment: You can use Cloud Dataproc. See here a use case example https://medium.com/google-cloud/moving-data-with-apache-sqoop-in-google-cloud-dataproc-4056b8fa2600

Answer (score 0):

Using BigQuery migration assessment feature we can migrate from data warehouse to BigQuery.
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/migration-assessment